# Initializing jagged arrays with Lists<int> inside by a for loop

Tags: c#, .net, list, jagged-arrays

I get NullReferenceException when I want to add item to my elements in jagged array.

```
public List<int>[][] Map;

void Start()
{
    Map = new List<int>[60][];
    for(byte x = 0; x < 60 ; x++)
    {
        Map[x] = new List<int>[60];
        // initialization of rows
    }

    Map [23] [34].Add (21);
}
```

Comment: before you can start adding items to your list, you need to instantiate your list.  I.E. `Map[23][34] = new List<Int>()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a jagged array which each of its elements is a `List<int>`. You initialize the array but not the elements.

So when you call `Add` on an uninitialized element which is a `List<int>` you get the exception.

```
Map = new List<int>[60][];
for (int x = 0; x < 60; x++)
{
    Map[x] = new List<int>[60];

    for (int y = 0; y < 60; y++)
    {
        Map[x][y] = new List<int>(); // initializing elements
    }
    // initialization of rows
}

Map[23][34].Add(21);
```

Comment: Hmm, thank you for your answer. One question to clarify:

When I make int arrays for example, the ints inside are initialized instantly, however in List arrays, Lists are not?

Comment: It's because int is a value type but `List<T>` is a reference type. When value types are initialized they get a value. For example int becomes 0 and bool becomes false but reference types default value is null. So when you try to access them you get NullReferenceException.

Comment: Ahh damn, thank you so much. I've been reading something about value/reference types and now these pieces of information finally begin to connect.